# convert dictionary key and value to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary

I know how to convert string to unicode using `unicode("string", "utf-8")` and I tried applying it to a dictionary. Well, my first solution is to loop everything (key and value) then convert them to unicode. But is there a fastest way to do this?

```
dict = {'firstname' : 'Foo', 'lastname' : 'Bar'}
```

To

```
dict = {u'firstname' : u'Foo', u'lastname' : u'Bar'}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's no shortcut - @perreal's answer is short and easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the 'unicode' function:

```
d = {'firstname' : 'Foo', 'lastname' : 'Bar'}
d = {unicode(k):unicode(v) for k,v in d.items() }
```

Comment: Wow! Never thought about this. Thanks!